# No module named ipykernel_launcher in VSCode

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I am trying to use the interactive window from VSCode which requires me to install ipykernel_launcher. The direct error message is `No module named ipykernel_launcher. View Jupyter log for further details.`

The log is awfully long but the most important information to me seems to be `[error] Failed to install ipykernel ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipykernel`

It seems the pip couldn't find ipykernel. I did not input any command myself in the terminal, the log above is the consequence of me starting the interative window, and then clicking install when VSCode prompts me with the message "Running cells with 'python_ari' requires the ipykernel package.

When trying to myself use `pip install ipykernel` the result is the same, with the terminal not finding the package.

Comment: `py -m pip install ipykernel --upgrade` Released: Feb 26, 2024

Answer (score 0):

Coworker helped me find the solution:

Windows 11 did not trust the sources from where Python downloads packages.
I had to manually tell my system to trust by adding arguments to the command:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Additionally, my venv was not activated. Rookie mistake.

```
'.\venv\Scripts\activate'
```